# Batch file: replace empty rows in text file

Tags: batch-file

New to this. Have tried to combine answers to related questions, but can't get it to work.

I want to create a batch file that reads a text file, replace any empty rows with e.g. '#', and then store the result in a new text file.

Possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst batch files aren't really the best choice for this type of task, you may be lucky enough that the following will suffice:

```bat
@(For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "file.txt"'
) Do @If "%%B"=="" (Echo #) Else Echo %%B)>"output.txt"
```